# Using Keras TimeseriesGenerator without labels

Tags: python, keras, time-series

I have some time series data and labels. I have already tried training some RNNs on them using `Keras`. For preparing the data for that, I used

```
train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(
    data_array,
    labels_array,
    length=100,
    batch_size=16,
    stride=100,
)
```

This way I could get data of length 100 without overlaps (since stride is set to 100), which is what I required. Also, I get one label per time series, which is also proper.

Now, I would like to train an autoencoder model. Is there a way to get just the data from the `TimeseriesGenerator` since passing the data twice in the `TimeseriesGenerator` doesn't work i.e. it considers the second argument as labels anyway and processes it as a label i.e. only one row is returned for the corresponding time series extracted from the first argument.

Is there any simple way to achieve this or do we need to develop a custom `DataGenerator` class?